# Execution cannot be found (rsExecutionNotFound)

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I keep getting the errror "Execution 'APPLICATION ID' cannot be found (rsExecutionNotFound)" using SQL Server Reporting. It keeps happening for the same user, with the same application ID. While it happens for some other users it happens a lot for this one user. I have tried increasing the session timeout as menetioned here: http://blogs.msdn.com/jgalla/archive/2006/10/11/session-timeout-during-execution.aspx. The users don't say they are experiencing any problems, just us web developers can see them in the exception reporting.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

We got around this issue with a client by clearing his web cache and deleting his cookies.  Weird...

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved this specific error for one user. This user could not run any reports using the report URL from her PC. She could run reports from other PCs though. I discovered that this user had not modified certain IE Internet\Scripting settings nor had this user downloaded the RSClientPrint ActiveX control. Not sure which of these was causing the problem, but when properly set and the user downloaded the RSClientPrint ActiveX control the error went away. Please note that my resolution might not work for you. I have a personal document with the needed settings but could not post them here. You will need to look in Books Online to obtain the internet settings necessary for running reports.

Comment: write neatly ..use bulleted points so that it is very easy to read..answer directly  to the question

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050593/execution-iwy2vpzo52pmp555ftfn4455-cannot-be-found-rsexecutionnotfound)

I hope this helps.